# RQL/RSQL (Resource query language) with reactjs (npm)

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, rest

I wanted to use RQL with `Reactjs`. I have already installed rql using `npm install rql --save`. But I don't know how to use it. I tried below -

```
import {Query} from 'rql/query';

// and inside component :- 
queryData(state){
  console.log(Query); #1
  var fetchQuery= Query.eq("city","IN" );
  console.log(fetchQuery);
}
```

but I am getting undefined at #1.
I couldn't find any documentation for the same. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried importing it like `const Query = require("rql/query").Query;`?

Comment: yes , have already tried the same , didn't work

Comment: @harpal18 Were you able to use this in React?